# Não consigo selecionar varios objetos do meu componentes

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando um componente do primefaces, só que quando vou selecionar vários item deste componente não consigo selecionar.

Estou usando um Enum, precisa ser um arrayList?

```
<h:outputLabel for="servico" value="Serviço:" />
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="servico" value="#{servicoBean.servico.tipoServico}" label="-- Selecione --" multiple="true"
          filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px" required="true">
          <f:selectItems value="#{servicoBean.tipoServicos}" var="tpServ" itemLabel="#{tpServ.descricao}" itemValue="tpServ" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Comment: Posta como o seu `#{servicoBean.tipoServicos}` está sendo preenchido.

Answer (score 0):

A variável servicoBean.servico.tipoServico precisa ser um tipo que receba vários objetos, mas você também precisará de um conversor porque o selectItems é preenchido com objetos SelectItem e não com TipoServico.